# If string does not match array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code that looks for windows titles, and closes them if they are in the array. This works great if the windows/title are there, if not, it just sit their ('cause I haven't told it to do anything).. and this is where I'm stuck ( and hoping for some help).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Windows Title";

    int i = 0;   // While Loop counter
    System.Console.WriteLine("Starting to look for pop-up windows....\n");

    while (i <= 9)        // while i is equal to , or less than 9......
    {
        string[] errorArray = { "Apple", "Banana", "pear", "plum", "pineapple", "0", "1", 
                                  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8,", "9" };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
        {
            string title = window.Value;

            if (errorArray.Any(title.Equals))
            {
                i++;                                                       
                System.Console.WriteLine("\nFound {0} of 9 error messages\n", i);// 
                int iHandle = FindWindow(null, title);
                SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} pop up closed\n", title);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            else
            {
               //wait for a 60 seconds , then 
            }
        }
    }
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

I'm stuck are to what to do in the ELSE section.
The app will run as a scheduled task. 
If its runs, and none of the open windows titles matches the array, then I would like it to close.
If the windows titles are present, then it (and does) start the code already in place, in increment i (till i = 9).

Can anyone help me on how to make it wait ?

thanks

Comment: you are already using *Thread.Sleep(5000);* why not use it in else condition ?

Comment: this is what I am getting confused about. if I put a "thread.sleep" in the ELSE condition, wont it sleep for 60 seconds for every title that currently open that isn't in the array?

Comment: @Gerald Oakham, you are telling it to freeze.  If you don't want it to freeze then look at the link in my question.  You will have to learn about asynchronous programming.

Comment: Why you need that `while` loop?

Comment: I use the while loop as I know there are 9 pops ups, so I incremented I each time 1 of the pop ups was found and close. why? is ther a better way to do this, and get the problem to close if there are no popups matching the titles in the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    bool finished=false;
    do
    {
    finished=false;

foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
            {
                string title = window.Value;

                if (errorArray.Any(title.Equals))
                {
                    i++;                                                       
                    System.Console.WriteLine("\nFound {0} of 9 error messages\n", i);// 
                    int iHandle = FindWindow(null, title);
                    SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} pop up closed\n", title);
                    finished=true;
                }
                else
                {
                   thread.Sleep(60000);
                   //wait for a 60 seconds , then 
                }


            }
} while (finished==false)
```

The main thread will go to sleep for 60 seconds if the following condition returns false:

```
if (errorArray.Any(title.Equals))
```

It will continue looping until the condition returns true.

Following from your comment.  If you want the method to run asynchronously (not clear from your question), then look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap

Comment: Hi, I've just tried this, and is causes the program to hang

Comment: I have changed the integer to a Boolean.

Comment: The program will hang for 60 seconds on each loop.  Do you want the method to run asynchronously?

Comment: hi, it just goes into the Else condition, and waits their.